BCP exports result in file corruption for non-PDF files
What I'm trying to do is use Bulk Copy Program to extract data from a VARBINARY column of my database and then download files of various types (PDFs, XLSs, TIFs, etc) to the user's hard drive.
At first I wasn't able to generate a any files that I was actually able to open due to data corruption.  Then once I started using an XML format file I've been able to generate and download PDF files that will open fine, but it still becomes corrupted with XLSs, TIFs, etc to the extent that the file either won't open or if they do they're pretty much unreadable. Word docs actually open okay but they are proceeded with a waring the 'Word found unreadable content'.
This is the content of my format file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="8"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="CONTENT" xsi:type="SQLBINARY"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>

And this is the command I'm using:
bcp "select CONTENTS from DOCUMENT_TABLE where DOC_ID = 123" queryout "C:\users\fred\bcp_files\BCP_results.xls" -c -d MyDatabase -S MyDatabaseServer  -f "C:\Users\fred\bcp_files\format_file.xml"

As I said it does fine with PDF files; the data gets corrupted with pretty much anything else.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

I'm not totally sure what you mean by getting a zip file - unless that's some intermediate file I'm not familiar with.
If I extract from a record that has data for a pdf file it generates a non-corrupted pdf file:
However if I try to do it with the contents from anything else such as an xls file the data gets corrupted.
And I know that the VARBINARY data is correct in each case and that I'm naming the file extension correctly.

Understood - thank you.  However it's doing it though it always creates a valid file that can be opened if the file is a PDF.  If the file is a word docx file, it opens and correctly displays the content but only after giving a 'Word found unreadable content' warning.  If it's an xls file and I try to open the resulting file it displays a warning that the file format and extension of the file don't match and then the xls opens but with very corrupted data.

Why are you using the -c (character data type) command line parameter if you're intending to export varbinary data?

Why are you using bcp at all? There are proper tools to read data from sql server, even powershell can do this stuff easy

The point of using bcp was so it could be done in a stored procedure.  The -c was just something I tried to possibly solve the problem.  It didn't help but didn't hurt either.

Thanks for all the suggestions.  Part of it has just been the drive to figure out what is going wrong.  I may just have to go a different route.
